# how to take backup of hyperledger fabric ca?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

If my ica goes down , how to restart with all the previously stored certificates.
how to take backup of hyperledger fabric **ica (ca generated using rootca )**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between root-CA and intermediate-CA interms of disaster recovery backup, both are fabric-ca’s

So please mount the following location `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca/fabric-ca-server.db` to docker volume  for both root-ca & ica

back-up will work fine as you expected till You remove the docker volume itself

> you can test by mounting the above-mentioned location  for both **root-ca &
>   ica** and create some identities then remove the containers and again
>   create containers now you will see previous identities